# How to update tailwindcss dynamically with template literals in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, template-literals

I'm having trouble with a Tailwind CSS class not updating in the browser, even though it appears to be updated in the DOM tree. Specifically, I'm trying to update the `left` property with a dynamic value in a string literal for a React component.

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    const MIN_VALUE = 10000;
    const MAX_VALUE = 20000;
    
    const InputRange = () => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(14000);
    
      const handleSliderChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setValue(parseInt(e.target.value));
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="mt-4 flex flex-col items-start w-full">
          <h2 className="text-base text-center text-primary-black font-bold">
            Update the range value
          </h2>
          <div className="relative pt-8 flex items-center justify-center w-full">
            <label
              htmlFor="rangeValue"
              className={`absolute top-0 left-[${value}px]`}
            >
              <span>RM{value}</span>
            </label>
            <input
              type="range"
              name="value"
              value={value}
              onChange={handleSliderChange}
              id="rangeValue"
              min={MIN_VALUE}
              max={MAX_VALUE}
              className="w-full"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default InputRange;
```

Here is the screenshot of the browser's DOM(chrome):

[image: Screenshot of browser's DOM(chrome)]

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind doesn't generate every possible class for every value you can put in. Instead, it checks your code for class names, and inserts them into the css file. If you want to change the positioning based on an arbitrary value, learn how css works and use inline styles.
[Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

```
<label
  htmlFor="rangeValue"
  className="absolute top-0"
  style={{ left: value }}
>
    <span>RM{value}</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are dynamically adding the `tailwindCSS` classes in the label. TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class…

```
className={`absolute top-0 left-[${value}px]`}>
```

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

Instead, you must include the full name of the class in your source code. You can return the full value by using a function like this

```
function  myDecoStyle(value) {
   return "absolute top-0 left-["+ value +"px]";
}
```

where `value` is the state you are passing here.

By doing it this way, the entire string for every class is in your source code, so TailwindCSS will know to generate the applicable CSS.

And use it like

```
           <label
              htmlFor="rangeValue"
              className={`${myDecoStyle(1400)}`}
            >
```

Read more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Comment: This will not fix the issue when changing the value in `handleSliderChange`, eten answer may work instead.

Comment: I guess @EmanueleScarabattoli is right. This will not fix the issue because according to the Tailwindcss documentation, I cannot use props to build class names dynamically as I write above instead I need to use map props to complete class names that are statically detectable at build-time.

Comment: You can invoke the myDecoStyle fn in the `handleSlider` fn after setting the value. then it should work